# How to match columns from 2 data frame and create a new data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

df1 and df2 are two data frames with multiple columns. I need to select a total number of columns in df2 based on df1. i.e if df1 has 4 columns, then we need to select 1st 4 columns from df2. Both have different data so intersection may not work. It's just the count of columns that needs to be the same.

```
df1

a   b    
12  23  
2   5    


df2

m  n  j   l  
12 12  2   9
2  3   4   5
```

Expected outcome

```
df3
m   n
12  12
2   3
```

Comment: `df2[, 1:ncol(df1)]`?

Comment: `df2[, seq_along(df1)]`

Comment: `df3 <- df2[,1:(ncol(df2) - ncol(df1))]`

Comment: `df2[1:length(df1)]`